# Mount usb drive with multiple mount points in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, udev

I want to automount usb drives with udev in a custom directory in ubuntu. Already have a rules file that works:

```
# get the label if present, otherwise assign one based on device/partition
ENV{ID_FS_LABEL}!="", ENV{dir_name}="%E{ID_FS_LABEL}"
ENV{ID_FS_LABEL}=="", ENV{dir_name}="usbhd-%k"

##########################
# CONNECTED
##########################

ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{ID_FS_USAGE}=="filesystem", RUN+="/bin/systemd-mount --no-block --discover --options=umask=0000 --collect $devnode '/mnt/usb/%E{dir_name}'"

##########################
# DISCONNECTED
##########################

ACTION=="remove", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{ID_FS_USAGE}=="filesystem", RUN+="/bin/systemd-mount --umount --no-block --discover --options=umask=0000 --collect $devnode '/mnt/usb/%E{dir_name}'", RUN+="/bin/rmdir '/mnt/usb/%E{dir_name}'"
```

It mounts usb driver to /mnt/usb/usb_drive

If I'm logged out it works well. If I'm logged in, it tries to mount to /media/username/usb_drive (Don't know who does it) and the mount point /mnt/usb/usb_drive does not work. Is there a way to mount them on both places at the same time?